# Centralize EJB exception handling

Tags: java, exception, interceptor, ejb-3.1

I have a set of EJBs. I want to handle the business exceptions those EJBs rise in a single way. Of course, it would be great if I implement that exception handling policy it in a single "point". I didn't find any best practice to achieve this, does anyone has already experienced something? Any suggestion? I was looking after Interceptor, could be a good idea or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, someone else already thought about it and yes, it could be a good idea:

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossaop/docs/2.0.0.GA/docs/aspect-framework/userguide/en/html/building.html